# find first longer row of ones than following rows of zeros in array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array filled with zeros and ones like that:

...00011000111100001100**1**1111100111...

it always starts with zeros and ends with ones.

I have to find the index of the beginning of the first row of ones, that is longer than the following row of zeros. The bold one above.

I have already set a with the index of the first one, and set b with the index of the last zero.

```
k = 0
Do While array(k) = 0

    k = k + 1

Loop

 a = k

l = endOfArray
Do While array(l) = 1

    l = l - 1

Loop

 b = l
```

How can i go on?

Comment: If you want the index of the first set of ones that is longer then the previous set of zeros, wouldn't that be the second set of ones in your example above? and not the 4th set of ones. Or have I misunderstood things?

Comment: no, i need a set of ones that is longer than following set of zeros not previous set of zeros.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetOnes(inputStrng As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim zeros As Variant, ones As Variant

    zeros = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(inputStrng, "1", " ")))
    ones = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(inputStrng, "0", " ")))

    For i = 0 To UBound(ones)
        If Len(ones(i)) > Len(zeros(i)) Then
            GetOnes = ones(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

to be exploited as follows:

```
Sub main()    
    MsgBox "the first 'ones' sequence longer then subsequent 'zero' sequence is:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbTab & GetOnes("0001100000111001111111")
End Sub
```

Comment: @Hambone, I wish it were, while it's only age... anyway thanks!

Comment: @daniäla, did you get through it?

Comment: @daniäla, it'd be nice of you giving proper feedback to people trying at helping you. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not fully tested, but something like this.  SORRY, I've coded > previous to, i'll change later.

```
Sub Testsing()

Dim strInput As String
Dim arrSplitInput() As String
Dim intLoop As Integer
Dim intZeroes As Integer
Dim intIndex As Integer

strInput = "0001100000111001111111"
arrSplitInput = Split(strInput, "0")

For intLoop = 0 To UBound(arrSplitInput)
    If arrSplitInput(intLoop) = "" Then
        intZeroes = intZeroes + 1
    Else
        If intIndex > 0 Then intZeroes = intZeroes + 1
        intIndex = intIndex + intZeroes
        If Len(arrSplitInput(intLoop)) > intZeroes Then
            Debug.Print Mid(strInput, intIndex - 1, Len(arrSplitInput(intLoop)))
            Stop
        Else
            intIndex = intIndex + Len(arrSplitInput(intLoop)) + 1
        End If

        intZeroes = 0

    End If

Next intLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't work like i need it. If i take 0001100000111001111111 the code returns 11 and this isn't the first index of longer set of ones then previous zeros. But thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, I did say it needs full testing :) , and I'd coded the wrong way round :)  The code was a suggestion to get you started, the fix is you need to have another variable to hold the total of intEmpties and the Len checks.  Use this code with the locals window showing and you'll see what's happening in arrSplitInput and see the fix logic.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is overkill for a simple array job, but just a taste of OO VBA to see what you could get if you needed to extend the information required from the block of 1s.

Put in a **Class module** (Alt-I-C) ***named NumBlock***

```
Option Explicit

Private pLength As Long
Private pIndex As Long

Public Property Get Length() As Long
    Length = pLength
End Property

Public Property Let Length(val As Long)
    pLength = val
End Property

Public Property Get Index() As Long
    Index = pIndex
End Property

Public Property Let Index(val As Long)
    pIndex = val
End Property
```

Regular module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getIndexOfLongerOnes(arr As Variant) As NumBlock

  If InStr(1, TypeName(arr), "()", vbTextCompare) < 1 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 888, , "The argument was not an array!"
  End If
  Dim switched As Boolean
  Dim a As Long, z As Long
  Dim ones As NumBlock, zeroes As NumBlock

  a = LBound(arr)
  z = UBound(arr)
  switched = True
  Set ones = New NumBlock
  Set zeroes = New NumBlock

  Dim i As Long
  For i = a To z
        If i > a Then
              If arr(i) <> arr(i - 1) Then
                    switched = True
              Else
                    switched = False
              End If
        End If
        If arr(i) = 1 Then
              If switched Then
                    If ones.Length > zeroes.Length Then
                          Set getIndexOfLongerOnes = ones
                          Exit Function
                    End If
                    Set ones = New NumBlock
                    ones.Length = 1
                    ones.Index = i
              Else
                    ones.Length = ones.Length + 1
              End If
        Else
              If switched Then
                    Set zeroes = New NumBlock
                    zeroes.Length = 1
                    zeroes.Index = i
              Else
                    zeroes.Length = zeroes.Length + 1
              End If
        End If

  Next i

End Function

Public Sub test()

  On Error GoTo handler
  Dim testArr As Variant
  Dim block As NumBlock
  testArr = Array(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
  Set block = getIndexOfLongerOnes(testArr)

  MsgBox "Index: " & block.Index & vbNewLine & "Length: " & block.Length

  Exit Sub
handler:
  MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler array job:

```
Public Function getArrIndex(arr As Variant) As Long
  Dim switched As Boolean
  Dim a As Long, z As Long, currOnesIndex As Long, currZeroesIndex As Long, currOnesLength As Long, currZeroesLength As Long
  getArrIndex = -1 'default to -1 as not found qualifying set of ones
  a = LBound(arr)
  z = UBound(arr)
  switched = True

  Dim i As Long
  For i = a To z
        If i > a Then
              If arr(i) <> arr(i - 1) Then
                    switched = True
              Else
                    switched = False
              End If
        End If
        If arr(i) = 1 Then
              If switched Then
                    If currOnesLength > currZeroesLength Then
                          getArrIndex = currOnesIndex
                          Exit Function
                    End If
                    currOnesLength = 1
                    currOnesIndex = i
              Else
                    currOnesLength = currOnesLength + 1
              End If
        Else
              If switched Then
                    currZeroesLength = 1
                    currZeroesIndex = i
              Else
                    currZeroesLength = currZeroesLength + 1
              End If
        End If

  Next i
End Function
```